# trying to replace string in variable with ";"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I believe it's a simple question, but I haven't find a solution and spent a few hours trying to figure up why it's not working.

In a variable I have a string: `_webconfig = new Object();`
and I want to insert a line after it some text.

I tried to do it with using `-replace` but it don't work ok, because the function will be 'hitting' more than one time, resulting with the pattern x2.

This is the code I am using now (which don't work) because of the `;` in the end of the `$pattern` variable:

```
 $Pattern = "_webconfig = new Object();"
 $replaceWith =  "$Pattern `n_webconfig.$key = `"$value`";"       

 # write-Host "Pattern: $Pattern, replaceWith: $replaceWith"
 $text= $text -replace $pattern, $replaceWith
```

- the variable `$text` at the end will be `js` file, and it needs to have `;` at the end of each line.

the result I want to have is:

```
_webconfig = new Object();
```

will become:

```
_webconfig = new Object();
_webconfig.env = "dev";
_webconfig.ServicesAppName= "Services";
```

- the 'keys' and 'values' containing the right values.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want to add a code line after the `_webconfig = new Object();`?

Comment: What are `key` and `value`? Is it a dictionary or 2 arrays?

Comment: `key ` and `value` are just strings that i get in this function `function Replace-add-update($text, $key, $value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably all you have to do is to **escape** your `regex` string because of the two parentheses:

```
$Pattern = "_webconfig = new Object();"
$replaceWith =  "$Pattern `n_webconfig.$key = `"$value`";"       

$text= $text -replace [regex]::Escape($pattern), $replaceWith
```

Answer (score 2):

If `key` and `value` are just strings then use `String.Replace`:

```
$Pattern = "_webconfig = new Object();"
$replaceWith =  "$Pattern `n_webconfig.$key = `"$value`";"       

# write-Host "Pattern: $Pattern, replaceWith: $replaceWith"
$text= $text.Replace($pattern, $replaceWith)
```